# LibreOffice Calc: How to control which values are incremented on drag down?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a complex formula in a cell with various references to other cells.

```
=INDEX($Sheet1.B1:B100;MATCH(C1;$Sheet1.D1:D100;0))
```

I want all cell in the same column to have the same formula with only one reference incremented. But if I select the field and drag down the little square all references are incremented.

[image]

So the following fields would have the values:

```
=INDEX($Sheet1.B2:B101;MATCH(C1;$Sheet1.D2:D101;0))
=INDEX($Sheet1.B3:B102;MATCH(C2;$Sheet1.D3:D102;0))
=INDEX($Sheet1.B4:B103;MATCH(C3;$Sheet1.D4:D103;0))
…
```

But what I need is:

```
=INDEX($Sheet1.B1:B100;MATCH(C1;$Sheet1.D2:D100;0))
=INDEX($Sheet1.B1:B100;MATCH(C2;$Sheet1.D2:D100;0))
=INDEX($Sheet1.B1:B100;MATCH(C3;$Sheet1.D2:D100;0))
…
```

That means all matrix should not be incremented, the single reference to column C has to be incremented. How can I do this, where it is not possible to to it manually as too many rows are affected?

Comment: Cross-posted to https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/142837/how-to-control-which-values-are-incremented-on-drag-down/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
=INDEX($Sheet1.B1:B100;MATCH(C1;$Sheet1.D1:D100;0))
```

use:

```
 =INDEX($Sheet1.$B$1:$B$100,MATCH(C1,$Sheet1.$D$1:$D$100,0))
```

Place a $ dollar sign before each column and row you don't want changed. That is $B$1 .... $B$100 .......... $D$1 ..... $D$100

Comment: Great short & direct answer! In my case, I use Ctrl + drag a lot to stop numbers from incrementing. But it doesn't work when you are referencing something, very simple: `=A2` becomes `=A3` even when pressing Ctrl while dragging down. The dollar signs indeed prevent this.